# Can integer with space still read as integer?

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn about Java, and I'm trying out to make a guess a number game, anyways i'm using

```
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
```

and

```
    inputLine = is.readLine();
    Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
```

I was wondering if there is anyways I can let the program to recognize and ingeter with a bunch of space as the integer, basically how can I code it so "0          " will be recognize as just 0?

Comment: Replace Integer.parseInt(stringGuess) with Integer.parseInt(stringGuess.trim())

Comment: Hmm... what does the documentation for `Integer.parseInt` say?

Comment: Well, you can try using `Scanner` for input, using the `.nextInt()` method. It will return the next integer value in any string, provided it is available. If you're only worried about spaces, then @Alex's answer is the best.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 does it recognise 1 7 8 9 as 1789? it seems that's what op wants....

Comment: Spaces where? Beginning, end, inbetween?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess.trim());
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29

Comment: Thnx a lot for the help and for the website!

Answer (score 1):

A more "powerful" tool would be to remove all non-digit characters from the string, which can be done like this:

```
int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Comment: I think i'm doing something that is not allowing this code to have a affect, but thank a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stringGuess!=null) {
int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int guess = 0

if(stringGuess != null) {
    try {
        guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess.trim());
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // inform user that the number was bad?
    }
}
```

If you need to handle spaces (or any non-number) between numbers also, you could use:

```
int guess = 0

if(stringGuess != null) {
    try {
        guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""));
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // inform user that the number was bad?
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dariusz *stringGuess.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "")* replaces all non-numbers with an empty string, so yes I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int guess = 0
if(sc.hasNextInt())
    guess = sc.nextInt();
```

However, it will detect a string like "1 2 3 4" as four different integers, not as 1234, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I actually want it to read "1 2 3 4" as 1234 but thanks for the info I'm sure it will come in handy later.

Comment: You're welcome. I would suggest that you use `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` as it shortens the code considerably.

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` can only omit the leading and tailing whitespaces.

If you wouldn't like to use `replace("\\D", "")`, I think you can implement a `parseInt()` method by yourself, you can copy the code of `Integer.parseInt` and add `if (s.charAt(i++) != ' ')` before `digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);` and change `Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix)` to `Character.digit(s.charAt(i),radix)`